# Change event not firing on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a script to copy the text of the source element to the target element when the quantity changes, either by arrow keys or clicking the + or minus buttons.

```js
$(':input').on('change keyup', function() {
    var subtotal = $('.p.price .amount').text();
    $('.price .amount').text(subtotal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity buttons_added">
    <input type="button" value="-" class="minus">
    <input type="number" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="plus">
</div>

<p class="price">Subtotal <span class="amount">$12.50</span></p>
```

If I click in the input box and use the arrow keys, it works fine but when I click the plus or minus keys, the target value is one behind the source value.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any code that would make the `+` and `-` buttons do anything. Also, you should use the `input` event instead of both `change` and `keyup`.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: You are the one who is saying that clicking the `+` and `-` buttons the target value is one behind the source value. I'm saying that clicking those buttons with the code you've provided does nothing because you haven't shown any code that would make them do anything.

Comment: And what do you mean by "target" value and "source" value. What exactly is supposed to happen when the value in the text field changes?

Comment: The + and - buttons are inputs so shouldn't they also be targeted on change and keyup? There's a subtotal span tag (source) that I am copying to another element (target). When the number in the input field changes, the source updates and I want to copy that to the target.

Comment: A button's value doesn't change through user input, so it never fires a `change` event and the only way to activate a button click through the keyboard is to give the button the focus and press ENTER and ENTER doesn't trigger `keyup`. You have said that you already have that part working, but you don't have any code that would do that.

Comment: Actually, the code is working whether I change the input value by keyboard or clicking the + or - buttons. Adding a short timeout seems to give me the result I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: There's no way your buttons are working based on the code you've shared. That's my point. And, setting a timeout should have nothing to do with this. There's more code you aren't sharing here.

Comment: Yes there's more code than I shared. I was simply trying to write some pseudo code from a WooCommerce store. I'm sorry I was not able to get the issue across but rest assured, the buttons are working. Thank you very much for your replies.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any code that runs when the buttons are clicked because buttons don't have values that change through user input, nor do they respond to `keyup` events. You say that you've got the buttons sort of working, but if that's the case, there's more code that you have that you didn't post.

See the comments inline below:

```js
$(function(){
  const basePrice = 12.5;  // Set base price in code for easy changes later
  
  // Get references to elements you'll work with
  const $input = $("input.qty");
  const $output = $('.price > .amount');
  
  let qty = 1;  // Keep track of qty
      
  // Initialize the output
  $($output).text(basePrice.toFixed(2));

  // Handle changes made to the input type=number
  $('input.qty').on('input', function() {
    updateSubtotal();
  });

  // Handle clicks to the buttons
  $('.minus, .plus').on('click', function() {
    updateSubtotal($(this));  // Send clicked button reference to the function
  });

  // Figure out the answer
  function updateSubtotal($btn){
    // If a button got us here...
    if($btn){
      // Increase or decrease the quantity based on which button was clicked
      $btn.val() === "+" ? qty++ : qty--;
      $input.val(qty);  // Update the input type=number
    }
    qty = $input.val();
    $output.text((basePrice * $input.val()).toFixed(2)); // Update the total
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity buttons_added">
    <input type="button" value="-" class="minus">
    <input type="number" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="plus">
</div>

<p class="price">Subtotal $<span class="amount"></span></p>
```

Comment: Why the `if($btn){` in `updateSubtotal($btn)` when you use `updateSubtotal();` in `$('input.qty').on('input',` ---hahah ! I would suggest staying at the OP's level before getting into to complex answer... ;) Cheers!

Comment: Because you might get to the function by a button click (in which case you need to know which) or by a direct change to the `input type="number"` (where you don't need to pass anything). Your answer doesn't address changes to the field directly and if you update it so that it does, you're going to find that you either have the same code twice or you can off-load it to a separate function (where it will only be written once [DRY]), in which case, you'll need a solution like mine.

Comment: Try yours then lolll That if blocks the number input change ;)

Comment: Changing the number with arrow ro keyboard number actually does not triger the math on the span text. -- So it doesnt do anything more than my snippet.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I simply forgot one line. It works now.

Comment: FYI: I am not in a mind-set for the best answer chase here... Just talking ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I always try to write the best answer I can, but in this case, being able to update the price by the buttons or the input is what the OP states he/she needs so the answer should include that. Your answer only does it with the buttons and if you were to set it up to do it both ways, you'd need a solution similar to mine, which answers the first question you asked.

Comment: I agree.... And all this in the context that SO is not a coding service... I was awaiting his(her) questions for more. But whatever... Good day. ;)